# Screen is not being repainted while playing windowframe for PC

Tags: technical-issues, windowframe

While playing the game [windowframe](https://gamejolt.com/games/windowframe/142664), I am having a problem where the game screen is not being repainted properly.

As I understand it, the little game window is supposed to follow your character around the screen as you traverse the maze. (Actual behavior is pictured below.)

When I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, or switch windows and come back, or drag other windows over top of windowframe, the area is repainted properly.

This really is impacting game play, as much of the spirit of the game is lost due to being able to see more expansive portions of the map than intended.

*(Graphics drivers are up-to-date. Currently using Nvidia GeForce 388.59 on Windows 7 x64. Have checked several different Windows 7 desktops/laptops, and all exhibit the same issue.)*

[image: windowframe problem]
[image: windowframe problem]

Comment: It makes me wonder if the game requires that certain Windows features be turned on.

Comment: Developer has even released an "accessible" version that displays the fake windows differently, for PCs that have trouble displaying the game (on my PC, the accessible version has the same issue as the original)

Comment: Tried it on windows 10 and 8.1 and both works. Don't have a windows 7 to try now :(

Comment: @Yuu Good to know, but bothersome, as I don't have a windows 10 or 8.1 to try now :(

Comment: On the upside, it has a nice aesthetic to it. Reminds me of finishing a game of Patience in Windows 3.1.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the Visual Effects properties? To do this, press Win+PgUp/Pause (alternatively, right-click on 'This Computer'), select 'Advanced System Settings', go to the 'Advanced' tab, select 'Settings...' under the Performance header. In the new window go to the 'Visual Effects' tab. Try setting it to 'Adjust for best performance' and see if that helps.